# Putty Session Manager fails

Tags: putty

Using Putty v0.77 and Putty Session Manager v0.50.189, on Windows 10.

When I try to connect from PSM, I get a popup with "puttygen, unrecognized option '-load'".

This is just bizarre, I used PSM years ago without a hitch, what is going on? Are these two versions incompatible, perhaps?

Is anyone aware of a package that contains both Putty and PSM and is known to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in a setting that can be found in the tray icon of the Session Manager. The setting for the location of putty.exe was incorrect.